# How can I resolve the recurring popup issue in IntelliJ IDEA while coding in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I've been encountering a persistent popup in IntelliJ IDEA whenever I'm writing Kotlin code. Despite attempting to address it, the popup continues to disrupt my workflow.Every time I write Kotlin code in IntelliJ IDEA, a popup appears intermittently, causing distraction and hindering productivity. This popup interrupts my coding process and requires manual dismissal, which is both frustrating and time-consuming. I've tried various troubleshooting methods, such as restarting IntelliJ IDEA, invalidating caches, and updating plugins, but the issue persists. Additionally, I've checked for any conflicting configurations or conflicting settings but haven't been able to pinpoint the root cause of this popup.I've extensively searched through IntelliJ IDEA documentation, Kotlin forums, and related Stack Overflow threads to find a solution to this problem. However, while I've come across similar issues reported by other users, the suggested fixes haven't resolved my specific problem. I've also explored IntelliJ IDEA's settings and experimented with different configurations to no avail.I'm seeking guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this persistent popup issue in IntelliJ IDEA when writing Kotlin code. Any insights, suggestions, or alternative approaches to tackle this problem would be greatly appreciated. And here is the image of this popup:

[image: enter code here]

Comment: Can you attach the full code and the version of IntelliJ IDEA?